# MultiPart Form Request is not reaching the SPRING Controller

Tags: java, spring, controller, multipartform-data

I'm firing the below POST request to upload a logo.
The request is reaching all the filters. But, it not coming inside the controller method.
No Exceptions are being thrown. Don't know how to debug this further. Need help to resolve this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}/logo", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE }, produces = { "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity uploadPhoto(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file)
{
    return null;
}
```

[image: POSTMAN SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 0):

what is response in postman is it 404.
is it possible add customExceptionHandler using  @ControllerAdvice

https://auth0.com/blog/get-started-with-custom-error-handling-in-spring-boot-java/

Comment: I'm using Spring Framework. Do you have any idea in spring?

Comment: spring framework which version is using? https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc

Comment: SpringVersion - 5.3.18

Comment: @ControllerAdvice will work with spring version 5